# Timer ID in timer call back is different from defined timer ID

Tags: c++, winapi, timer, callback

I implemented two timers with `SetTimer` function :

```
UINT TimerId1 = SetTimer(NULL, IDT_TIMER1, 2000, TimerProc);
UINT TimerId2 = SetTimer(NULL, IDT_TIMER2, 2000, TimerProc);
```

And pump windows messages with `GetMessage` loop to get timer messages too :

```
#define IDT_TIMER1  1
#define IDT_TIMER2  2

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    MSG Msg;
    UINT TimerId1 = SetTimer(NULL, IDT_TIMER1, 2000, TimerProc);
    UINT TimerId2 = SetTimer(NULL, IDT_TIMER2, 2000, TimerProc);

    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Due to handle timer messages, i implemented my custom function `callback` for my timer :

```
VOID CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND hWnd, UINT nMsg, UINT nIDEvent, DWORD dwTime)
{
    if (nMsg == WM_TIMER)
    {
        switch (nIDEvent)
        {
        case IDT_TIMER1:
            cout << "Timer 1" << endl;
            break;
        case IDT_TIMER2:
            cout << "Timer 2" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in my `callback`, i cannot get the correct timer id because none of the cases are `true`. My timer id(s) defined as `1` and `2`, but timer id(s) in `callback` are absolutely different, its something like `31270`.

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thread timers (when `hWnd` is null), as opposed to window timers, do not use the ID you give them - instead they assign their own, which is returned to you by the `SetTimer` function.

This is described in the docs for [SetTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer):

> If the hWnd parameter is NULL, and the nIDEvent does not match an
> existing timer then it is ignored and a new timer ID is generated.

Note that once a thread timer is created, you can use that ID in future calls to `SetTimer` to modify it.

Comment: sorry, I didnt understand exactly. please explain more and what is the solution?

Comment: @BattleTested_закалённыйвбою You have to use the return value from `SetTimer` as the timer ID, you can't provide your own.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution :

At first notice that in the second parameter of `SetTimer` function according microsoft page (as [**@Jonathan Potter**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68280947/timer-id-in-timer-call-back-is-different-from-defined-timer-id/68281217#68281217) guidance) :

`nIDEvent`

*Type: UINT_PTR*

**A nonzero timer identifier. If the hWnd parameter is NULL, and the nIDEvent does not match an existing timer then it is ignored and a new timer ID is generated.**

So, my *hWnd* for timers are both `NULL` and there's no matching timer id with `1` and `2`. consequently timer id returned by `SetTimer` (which desired id according application decision) and i have to use that to handle in my `callback`.

```
// Defined as public to use in callback
UINT TimerId1;
UINT TimerId2;
```

And my `callback` defined as the following :

```
VOID CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND hWnd, UINT nMsg, UINT nIDEvent, DWORD dwTime)
{
    if (nMsg == WM_TIMER)
    {
        if (nIDEvent == TimerId1)
        {
            cout << "Timer 1" << endl;
        }

        if (nIDEvent == TimerId2)
        {
            cout << "Timer 2" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The output is :

```
Timer 2
Timer 1
Timer 2
Timer 1
Timer 2
Timer 1
.
.
.
```